# Expression lambda Dynamic Parameter

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, expression

In my current project, the repository used EntityFramework, with many tables as News.
So each time, we have a new input functional, we create the related database, generate the edmx, create a new method in the repository.
Example: db.News.Where(c=>c.Name=='myNews');
db.Articles.Where(c=>c.ArticleName=='myArticle');

I search a way to avoid to write each time a code really similar.

I created this code using Generic.
So it's a sample of code, the idead is ok, I can create a standard method by taking propertyName and string search, at first. It works.

The declaration

```
public class SampleClass
{
    public string SomeField = "Test";
}

public class ConfSampleClass2
{
    public Type Type { get; set; }
}
```

The call :

```
IQueryable result = GetCompaniesA<SampleClass2>("Name", "alpine");
```

The method :

```
public IQueryable GetCompaniesA<T>(string propertyName, string search)
{
try
{                
IQueryable<T> results = null;
SampleClass2 sc2 = new SampleClass2();
List<SampleClass2> listSc2 = new List<SampleClass2>();
listSc2.Add(new SampleClass2() { Name = "alpine" });
listSc2.Add(new SampleClass2() { Name = "Statue" });
listSc2.Add(new SampleClass2() { Name = "Gateau" });

//listSc2.Where(c => c.Name == "alpine");
IQueryable<SampleClass2> queryableData = listSc2.AsQueryable<SampleClass2>();

// Compose the expression tree that represents the parameter to the predicate.
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T),typeof(T).Name);
Expression member = Expression.Property(pe, typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName));
Expression left = Expression.Call(member, typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower",   System.Type.EmptyTypes));
Expression right = Expression.Constant(search);
Expression e1 = Expression.Equal(left, right);                
MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression =
Expression.Call(
typeof(Queryable),
"Where",
new Type[] { queryableData.ElementType },
queryableData.Expression,
Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(e1, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }));                
return queryableData.Provider.CreateQuery(whereCallExpression);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
throw ex;
}
}
```

But I would like to go further by avoid to use generic but using dynamic to avoid the name coupling.
So I modify the method to obtain this one:

The call:

```
Console.WriteLine(GetCompaniesDynamic(new ConfSampleClass2(){ Type=typeof(SampleClass2) },"Name", "alpine"));
```

The method :

```
public IQueryable GetCompaniesDynamic(dynamic dynamicObj, string propertyName, string search)
{
try
{
    IQueryable results = null;
    SampleClass2 sc2 = new SampleClass2();
    List<SampleClass2> listSc2 = new List<SampleClass2>();
    listSc2.Add(new SampleClass2() { Name = "alpine" });
    listSc2.Add(new SampleClass2() { Name = "Statue" });
    listSc2.Add(new SampleClass2() { Name = "Gateau" });
    IQueryable<SampleClass2> queryableData = listSc2.AsQueryable<SampleClass2>();

    ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(dynamicObj.Type, dynamicObj.Type.Name);
    Expression member = Expression.Property(pe, dynamicObj.Type.GetProperty(propertyName));
    Expression left = Expression.Call(member, typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", System.Type.EmptyTypes));
    Expression right = Expression.Constant(search);
    Expression e1 = Expression.Equal(left, right);

    //the issue appears on this line ParameterExpression of type   //'EntityFrameworkGeolocationExpression.SampleClass2' cannot be used for delegate parameter //of type 'System.Object', I can't compile if I replace Object by Dynamic.
    MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression =
        Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable),
            "Where",
            new Type[] { queryableData.ElementType },
            queryableData.Expression,                        
            Expression.Lambda<Func<Object, bool>>(e1, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }));
    return results = queryableData.Provider.CreateQuery(whereCallExpression);                
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
}
```

I try to find a way to really passed a dynamic object, so in my repository I will replace the news, article and objects called with simple query by an expression three.. I find many topic, and with someone, I read it's not possible. My next step after is to evolve the expression three by evolve the parameters.

Can you help me to go further?

Best regards,
Alexandre

Comment: Maybe you should just code against EF directly: `db.News.Where(c=>c.Name=='myNews')`. Why is that not working for you?

Comment: Thanks for your proposition BUT, I would like to evolve my code, I don't have only news and article, I have now around 30 tables so, I search a generic solution permitting to render generic the call. This permit to also abstract more further the repository call.

Comment: @user2416437 - Abstracting it so you can use strings or `dynamic` instead of actual properties is a bad idea.  You lose type safety, you lose compile errors when your object changes, and you lose intellisense.  This is a bad idea all around.

Comment: Not agree with you. I change my mind after to use it. So I continu to try to improve my knowledge. Is someone has an idea about how to solve my case?

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, I think this is a bad idea.  However, there's an (untested) trivially simple way to implement the behavior I think you're looking for.

```
public IQueryable GetCompaniesDynamic(string table, string property, string search)
{
    using (var context = new DBContext())
    {
        return context.Database.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo." + table + " WHERE "
                                        + property + " = '" + search  + "'");
    }
}
```

You use it like:

```
var companies = GetCompaniesDynamic("News", "Name", "myNews");
```

Note that this leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection if you don't sanitize your input, spelling mistakes and typos which you won't catch until your application blows up at runtime, and simply forgetting what fields are called.  I don't know why you're using entity framework when you explicitly don't want any of the features it provides.  But good luck.